# Minimize repetition between the same function definition sync and async

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have 2 code paths, 1 sync and 1 async.  I want them to have the same behavior except for their synchronicity flavor.

To do this, I'm trying to have as much code in common between them, as DRY as I can.

Here is my problem:

```py
def my_func(conn, several, keyword, arguments, that, are, tedious, to, refactor, but, must, be, explicit):
  query = template(keyword, arguments, that, are, tedious, to, refactor, but, must, be, explicit)
  res = find_all_sync(conn, query)
  return res

async def my_func(conn, several, keyword, arguments, that, are, tedious, to, refactor, but, must, be, explicit):
  query = template(keyword, arguments, that, are, tedious, to, refactor, but, must, be, explicit)
  res = await find_all_async(conn, query)
  return res
```

As you see, I have an embedded logic to call `find_all_sync` vs `find_all_async`, and await the latter---so I can't simply write a sync and wrap it in an async wrapper.  I internally call a slightly different function.

Most of the rest of my logic is contained in the templating step, but I can't find any way to further abstract the repetition of the tedious arguments while still having them listed explicitly.  What I'd imagine is something like....

```py
# how can I make this /definition/ choose correctly sync or async?
def _my_func(conn, several, keyword, arguments, that, are, tedious, to, refactor, but, must, be, excplicit, is_async=False):
  query = template(keyword, arguments, that, are, tedious, to, refactor, but, must, be, excplicit)
  if is_async:
    # this doesn't work. Look my outer function is sync
    res = await find_all_async(conn, query)
  else:
    res = find_all_sync(conn, query)
  return res
```

Is there an easier way to have one code path for sync + async?  Am I overlooking something simple?  (I'm also open to slightly more complicated options like inspecting the arguments inside the function.)

Comment: Just a note---the lack of DRYness here is so severe even writing this problem out, I copied the argument list incorrectly in the first draft and left some arguments off one of the 6 places it is defined!

Comment: You could simplify the API by building the query outside of these two functions and passing it to whichever `find_all` is used by your code.

Answer (score 3):

There's a decorator in the `curio` package that allows a function to have an async and sync implementation, which can be found here:
https://github.com/dabeaz/curio/blob/master/curio/meta.py#L118

Here's the decorator implementation:

```py
def awaitable(syncfunc):
    '''
    Decorator that allows an asynchronous function to be paired with a
    synchronous function in a single function call.  The selection of
    which function executes depends on the calling context.  For example:
        def spam(sock, maxbytes):                       (A)
            return sock.recv(maxbytes)
        @awaitable(spam)                                (B)
        async def spam(sock, maxbytes):
            return await sock.recv(maxbytes)
    In later code, you could use the spam() function in either a synchronous
    or asynchronous context.  For example:
        def foo():
            ...
            r = spam(s, 1024)          # Calls synchronous function (A) above
            ...
        async def bar():
            ...
            r = await spam(s, 1024)    # Calls async function (B) above
            ...
    '''
    def decorate(asyncfunc):
        if inspect.signature(syncfunc) != inspect.signature(asyncfunc):
            raise TypeError(f'{syncfunc.__name__} and async {asyncfunc.__name__} have different signatures')

        @wraps(asyncfunc)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if from_coroutine():
                return asyncfunc(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return syncfunc(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapper._syncfunc = syncfunc
        wrapper._asyncfunc = asyncfunc
        wrapper._awaitable = True
        wrapper.__doc__ = syncfunc.__doc__ or asyncfunc.__doc__
        return wrapper
    return decorate
```

(Note the use of `inspect.signature` to quickly check that the two functions are compatible.)
The method it uses to determine the calling context is tied-up in this function:

```py
def from_coroutine(level=2, _cache={}):
    f_code = _getframe(level).f_code
    if f_code in _cache:
        return _cache[f_code]
    if f_code.co_flags & _CO_FROM_COROUTINE:
        _cache[f_code] = True
        return True
    else:
        # Comment:  It's possible that we could end up here if one calls a function
        # from the context of a list comprehension or a generator expression. For
        # example:
        #
        #   async def coro():
        #        ...
        #        a = [ func() for x in s ]
        #        ...
        #
        # Where func() is some function that we've wrapped with one of the decorators
        # below.  If so, the code object is nested and has a name such as <listcomp> or <genexpr>
        if (f_code.co_flags & _CO_NESTED and f_code.co_name[0] == '<'):
            return from_coroutine(level + 2)
        else:
            _cache[f_code] = False
            return False
```

This involves some pretty gnarly frame hacks, but it should get you where you want to go.  If you're only interested in determining if a function is a coroutine or not there's `inspect.iscoroutinefunction`:

```py
>>> import inspect
>>> async def f():
...     ...
...
>>> inspect.iscoroutinefunction(f)
True
>>> def g():
...     ...
...
>>> inspect.iscoroutinefunction(g)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write either an async or a regular function and then use library like [unsync](https://github.com/alex-sherman/unsync) so it will be executed in the event loop or thread/process executor according to its type.

Some examples from `unsync` [doc](https://github.com/alex-sherman/unsync#examples):

```
@unsync
async def unsync_async():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 'I like decorators'

@unsync
def non_async_function(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return 'Run concurrently!'
```

Comment: This doesn't work because of the await embedded inside the function needs to be different depending.